# Copy a column from a table to an other using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I have a shapefile and I want to copy two fields from it to an other table which is empty. Any idea about how to do it? I'm using QGIS 2.18.1.

Answer (score 4):

- If you need to relate the attributes with other geofeatures, you need to JOIN with another table. There are a few tutorials, how to JOIN two sources, e.g. http://www.qgistutorials.com/en/docs/performing_table_joins.html.
- If you just need to extract columns, table data are stored in DBF format. Locate your shapefile on the hardrive and open DBF file in LibreCalc or Excel (don't forget to make a copy before making any change to prevent corrupting the DBF format).

Comment: What i want to do is copy a column of  a shapefile in a postgis layer. The join wont work because the table that I want to fill is empty.